# Is it possible to get provider information from a EF Core 7 PropertyBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to create a `PropertyBuilder` extension that creates the correct UUID auto-generation code based on the DBMS and version.

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
public static PropertyBuilder AutoIncrementGuid(this PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder)
{
    var providerCode = ""; // get a unique id for the database type and version

    switch (providerCode)
    {
        case "SQL SERVER":
            return propertyBuilder.ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        case "PostgreSQL.13+":
            return propertyBuilder.HasDefaultValueSql("gen_random_uuid()");

        case "PostgreSQL.12-":
            return propertyBuilder.HasDefaultValueSql("uuid_generate_v4()");

        ...
    }

    return propertyBuilder;
}
```

I'm not seeing any way to get the provider name or version from `PropertyBuilder`.

Does anyone know if there is a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Provider information is not available until after the context has finished initializing. So it's not available during entity configuration.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't get a `ProviderCode`, but you can get a `ProviderName` by:

```cs
var modelBuilder = propertyBuilder.Metadata.DeclaringEntityType.Model.Builder;
var dbContext = ((Model) modelBuilder.Metadata).GetDbContext();
string providerName = dbContext.Database.ProviderName;

// ... switch-case according to the name.
```

Comment: 'Builder' property doesn't seem to exist on 'DeclaringEntityType.Model'. Also I can't seem to find a 'Model' class that has GetDbContext(). Maybe that all only applies to EntityFramwork and not EF Core.